# Adding Blank Slide to PowerPoint in VBA using ppLayoutCustom

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I read the object browser and its signature about [Slides.AddSlide method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide).

```
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, pCustomLayout:=ppLayoutCustom)
```

However, when I run this in my Macro, I get the error:

ppLayoutCustom gets highlighted and "Compile error: Type mismatch".

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

Blank slides are a preset layout, not a custom one. Here's how to add a blank slide:

```
Public Sub BlankSlide()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
 
    Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=2, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where you got `ppLayoutCustom` from.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide has this example code which you might be following?

```vb
Public Sub Add_Example() 
 
    Dim pptSlide As Slide 
    Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout 
 
    Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout       '  do this first
    Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout) 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Updated the post. However, this adds a slide with a layout identical to slide 1!

Comment: Yes that's what that code does.  What other outcome did you want?